# HTML and PHP posting in file error

Tags: php, html

I am making a poll with HTML and PHP and I want to post the poll answers in a text file. I have 6 things to choose from.

The name is answer and the values are `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, `a6`. How to post `a1` or `a2` or `a3`... in the file.

You know when you click on the answer with id a1 to post in a new line `a1` in the file.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="php/vote.php"> 
  <b><strong>Vote:</strong></b> <br> 
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a1" id="a1">a<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a2" id="a2">b<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a3" id="a3">c<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a4" id="a4">d<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a5" id="a5">e
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Vote"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far?

Comment: <form action="php/vote.php">
        <b><strong>Vote:</strong></b>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a1" id="a1">a<br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a2" id="a2">b<br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a3" id="a3">c<br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a4" id="a4">d<br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a5" id="a5">e<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Vote">
    </form>

Comment: Is there a question here that I don't see?

Comment: Can you show us vote.php ?

Comment: Your question title says you have an error. What is the error?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="bg">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body background="img/secondpagebg.jpg">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
   file_put_contents("data.txt", $_POST['answer']."\n");
}
?>
<h1></h1>
<div id="empty">
</div>

<div id="img">
<img src="img/funnyFace.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: fantasy;
 color: white;
}
#img {
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 1;

}
#empty {
 height: 80px;
}
body {
background-size:100%;
}
</style>

Comment: It doesn't post the words in data.txt. I am using that hosting : https://byet.host/free-hosting

Comment: Please note that you can (and should) post code in your own question. If you scatter it across unformatted comments it's just impossible to understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you are asking:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
   file_put_contents("filename.txt", $_POST['answer']."\n");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <b><strong>Vote:</strong></b> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a1" id="a1">a<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a2" id="a2">b<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a3" id="a3">c<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a4" id="a4">d<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a5" id="a5">e
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Vote">
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

I have added `method="POST"` to your original HTML so that the receiving PHP can inspect the `$_POST` variable to see what was sent through from the form. `$_POST['answer']` contains the value of the "value" field corresponding to the selected radio button. Once you know this, it is easy to call `file_put_contents` to write that value to your file. Append a newline "\n" to ensure that each call writes to a separate line of the file.